# Combining address function and cell function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, lookup

In MS Excel 2013, when I write

```
=CELL("contents",$B$1)
```

It is okay, but when I write

```
=CELL("contents",ADDRESS(1,2))
```

It results in error. I would like to access the contents of an address. I have done it before, but forgot for the moment.

Correcting this idea or another idea both would be welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you enter `=CELL("contents",ADDRESS(1,2))` you are expecting Excel to evaluate that expression to `=CELL("contents",$B$1)`.

This isn't quite what Excel does. Excel will read it as `=CELL("contents","$B$1")`. Note the quotes - Excel thinks this is a string, not a cell reference. This is why you get an error.

To convert the string output of `ADDRESS()` to a cell ref you can adjust your formula slightly like this:

```
=CELL("contents",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,2)))
```

The `INDIRECT()` function simply converts your string into a real cell reference Excel can use.

Comment: You still deserve kudos for that. I needed to store an address in a cell to be used as parameter for a VLOOKUP.

Comment: Glad it helped :)